Continuous Indexing Issue in PhpStorm
I am reaching out regarding a persistent issue I've been encountering with continuous indexing in PhpStorm.
For the past 24 hours, PhpStorm has been stuck in an indexing loop, causing significant disruptions in my workflow. Despite waiting patiently, the indexing process has not completed, making it extremely challenging to search for files or perform any other actions efficiently within the IDE.
To address this problem, I have already taken the following steps:

Excluded the log folder from indexing in the directory settings.
Tried restarting PhpStorm multiple times.
Invalidated caches and restarted PhpStorm.
Verified that my system meets the minimum requirements for PhpStorm.

Despite these efforts, the indexing process remains ongoing and has not shown any signs of progress.
How to resolve this issue and stop the continuous indexing?


Report to Youtrack of PhpStorm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/projects/dec98b17-9fc8-41f2-a054-1afb387d0472

Create a support ticket via Help | Contact Support... where you will be able to privately provide all required information (log files etc.) It should be a support matter at the moment, not a bug report straight away.

Just a wild guess, but any chance you have a MongoDB database? It might be the following issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-20515

My PHPstorm was reindexing in loop, using all the CPU possible.
In the logs (~/.cache/JetBrains/PhpStorm2024.1/log/idea.log) I saw this error happening very often :
2024-05-23 13:17:49,509 [ 499097] INFO - #c.i.u.i.i.MapReduceIndex - An exception during updateWithMap(). Index php.generator.operands.type.index will be rebuilt. com.intellij.util.indexing.StorageException: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: encoded string (#-#E#o#-...n)∆n∆m∆n) too long: 162922 bytes at com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.updateWithMap(MapReduceIndex.java:372) at 

Unfortunately it doesn't give the name of the file that causes problems.
But I deleted everything in my var/cache folder (in my Symfony project)
And now it has returned to normal :)
I hope this will help someone with the same problem.
